# Path of Oracle.DataAccess.dll file on a linux server

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am looking for the path of Oracle.DataAccess.dll file on a linux server.
Usual location of the file is:
"/Database/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ODP.NET/bin/2.x"

But there is no directory named ODP.NET in the location "/Database/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/"

I also tried searching for the directory using the following command.
find  / -name "ODP.NET"

Anyone has solution for this problem?

Comment: Which kernel are you referring to? Try referring to this http://www.howtogeek.com/112674/how-to-find-files-and-folders-in-linux-using-the-command-line/

Comment: kernel version 3.0.76-0.11-default. I tried find command but it dint help.

Answer (score 0):

DDLs are libraries for windows. Those libraries do not work on Linux. 
AFAIK, ODP.NET means "Oracle Data Provider" for [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), whichis a Microsoft framework and probably does not work with Linux